# Find modified files between 2 timestamps using bash script

Tags: linux, files, find, date

I want to find out the files which changed between some interval.
Script I am using is

```
#!/bin/bash
find ./ -type f -newermt '2018-05-24 09:26:50' ! -newermt '2018-05-24 09:26:52'
```

My folder contains the following files:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  219 May 24 09:26 sql_runner.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3.6K May 24 09:26 script.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3.1K May 24 09:26 script_ide.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 8.8K May 24 09:26 q
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   17 May 24 09:26 program.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  346 May 24 09:26 main.c
drwx------ 2 root root  12K May 24 09:26 lost+found
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1.7K May 24 09:26 javaRunner.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 May 24 09:26 inputParams
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    2 May 24 09:26 inputForInfinite
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   14 May 24 09:26 inputFile
```

When I run the above script it does not return anything but when I change script to this

```
#!/bin/bash
find ./ -type f -newermt '2018-05-24 09:26:49' ! -newermt '2018-05-24 09:26:52'
```

i.e. decreasing time by 1 second (from `2018-05-24 09:26:50` to `2018-05-24 09:26:49`), it gives me the required result:

```
./inputFile
./main.c
./sql_runner.sh
./script_ide.sh
./q
./inputForInfinite
./javaRunner.sh
./program.txt
./inputParams
./script.sh
```

Why am I having such a behaviour because the output of `date -r ./sql_runner.sh` gives is:

```
Thu May 24 09:26:50 UTC 2018
```

What should I change in this script to have desired behaviour?

Comment: The first `-newermt` argument ask for files newer than `09:26:50`. But `09:26:50` is not newer than `09:26:50`.

Comment: And hence the change in the script to have the desired behaviour is exactly what you did, i.e. make the time one second earlier.

Comment: Beware `date -r` doesn't show the nanoseconds by defaut. With  GNU `date`, you can use `date -r file --iso-8601=ns` or with GNU `stat`: `stat -c %y file`. Note that for symlinks, `date` gives you the mtime of the target while `stat` (and `ls -l`) gives you the mtime of the symlink.

Comment: @ Sparhawk Ok, can i mention milliseconds then to differentiate between the files which were created after like 09:26:50:200 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the timestamp of `sql_runner.sh` (and the other files) is between 09:26:49.000 and 09:26:49.999; therefore, it is newer than ...49 but not newer than ...50. If you want to split <strike>hairs</strike> seconds, [GNU find](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/findutils.git/tree/find/pred.c#n134) will compare timestamps down to the nanosecond:

```
/* Returns ts1 - ts2 */
static double ts_difference (struct timespec ts1,
                 struct timespec ts2)
{
  double d =  difftime (ts1.tv_sec, ts2.tv_sec)
    + (1.0e-9 * (ts1.tv_nsec - ts2.tv_nsec));
  return d;
}


static int
compare_ts (struct timespec ts1,
        struct timespec ts2)
{
  if ((ts1.tv_sec == ts2.tv_sec) &&
      (ts1.tv_nsec == ts2.tv_nsec))
    {
      return 0;
    }
  else
    {
      double diff = ts_difference (ts1, ts2);
      return diff < 0.0 ? -1 : +1;
    }
}
```

[You were close](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/445711/find-modified-files-between-2-timestamps-using-bash-script#comment807963_445711) with the syntax; use a period to add the fractional seconds, not another colon:

```
find ./ -type f -newermt '2018-05-24 09:26:50.200' ...
```